# Python multiple rows to one row

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a question per below - I need to transform multiple rows of ID into one row, and let the different "output"-values become columns with binary 1/0, like example.

Here is my table!

```
ID    Output      Timestamp
1     out1        1501
1     out2        1501
1     out5        1501
1     out9        1501
2     out3        1603
2     out4        1603
2     out9        1603
```

To be transformed into the following:

```
ID     out1     out2     out3     out4     out5     out9      timestamp
1      1        1        0        0        1        1         1501
2      0        0        1        1        0        1         1603
```

Can someone help me do this in a flexible way in Python, preferably Pandas? I'm quite new to this, have been using SAS for a good many years so any "transition tips" are greatly appreciated.

Br,

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I have been down the lines of doing a pivot like matt_s suggested below, but didnt come all the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pivot:

```
pivoted = df.pivot('ID', 'Output', 'ID')
pivoted.fillna(0, inplace=True)
pivoted[pivoted > 0] = 1
pd.merge(pivoted.reset_index(), df[['ID', 'Timestamp']].drop_duplicates(), left_on='ID', right_on='ID')
pivoted
```

Result:

```
 Output ID  out1    out2    out3    out4    out5    out9    Timestamp
 0  1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1501
 1  2   0   0   1   1   0   1   1603
```

Comment: This looks like a simple and flexible solution, Im going to work on it! Thank you so much for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a dictionary, where the key is the id.  Each value of that is going to be another dictionary of outN to value.

Read a line. You get an id, outN, and a value. Check you have an dict for that id first, and if not, create one. Then shove the value for that outN into the dict for that id.

Second step: You need to collect a list of all the outNs. Make a new set. For each value in your dict, add each of its outN keys to your set. At the end, get a list from the set, and sort it.

Third step: Go through each id in your dict keys, and then each outn in your new sorted list of outns, and print the value of that, with a fallback to zero.   `outnval_by_ids[id].get(outn, "0")`

There's a weird case here, in that you have a lot of timestamps that you are assuming are duplicate by id. Be careful that is really the case. Assumptions like that cause bugs.

Comment: Im going to give this a go when I have gotten my problem through - answer above got me through the worst! Thank you for the input!